# Comparación lenta de valores entre dos listas con diferentes propiedades

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo dos listas que comparten dos propiedades y el valor de esas propiedad comparo sin son iguales en ambas listas.

La primera clase

```
public class ClassAnterior
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Descripcion { get; set; }
  public int Cantidad { get; set; }
  public int Estado { get; set; }
}
```

La segunda clase

```
public class ClassActual
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Lleno la información en las listas

```
//Datos lista anterior 1
  var anterior1 = new ClassAnterior()
  {
    Id = 12,
    Cantidad = 34,
    Descripcion = "abcd",
    Estado = 1
  };
  var anterior2 = new ClassAnterior()
  {
    Id = 22,
    Cantidad = 67,
    Descripcion = "wxyz",
    Estado = 2
  };
  List<ClassAnterior> listaAnterior = new List<ClassAnterior>();
  listaAnterior.Add(anterior1);
  listaAnterior.Add(anterior2);

//Datos lista actual 2
  var actual1 = new ClassActual()
  {
    Id = 12,
    Estado = 1
  };
  var actual2 = new ClassActual()
  {
    Id = 43,
    Estado = 5
  };
  List<ClassActual> listaActual = new List<ClassActual>();
  listaActual.Add(actual1);
  listaActual.Add(actual2);
```

Ambas tienen la misma longitud pero desconozco si tienen los mismos valores y hago un contador si la condición se cumple.

```
  var contador = 0;
  var countListaAnterior = listaAnterior.Count(); 
  var countListaActual = listaActual.Count();

  if(countListaActual == countListaAnterior)
  {
     foreach (var x in listaActual)
     {
       foreach (var y in listaAnterior)
       {
         if (x.Id == y.Id && x.Estado == y.Estado)
         {
            contador++;
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

Si el contador es igual a la longitud de la lista significaría que son iguales también los valores de ambas listas. Funciona pero es lento

```
if (contador == countListaActual)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Son iguales ambas listas");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No son iguales");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer puedes resolverlo con un solo **ciclo for**, ej:

```
var contador = 0;
var countListaAnterior = listaAnterior.Count(); 
var countListaActual = listaActual.Count();

if(countListaActual == countListaAnterior)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < countListaActual; i++)
   {
      var x = listaActual.ElementAt(i);
      var y = listaAnterior.ElementAt(i);

      if (x.Id == y.Id && x.Estado == y.Estado)
      {
         contador++;
      }         
   }
}
```

Hacemos un solo **ciclo for**, y en cada iteracion del **ciclo** obtenemos los elementos actuales, tanto de **listaAnterior** como de **listaActual** usando la funcion **ElementAt**, la cual recibe como parametro un entero que seria la posicion del elemento a obtener dentro de una lista. Hacemos la comparacion y en caso de que se cumpla la condicion de igualdad incrementamos la **variable contador**.

Posteriormente hariamos esto:

```
if (contador == countListaActual)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Son iguales ambas listas");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("No son iguales");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Si la **variable contador** es igual a la longitud de las listas mostramos un mensaje que diga que las listas son iguales, caso contrario, imprimimos otro mensaje diciendo que las listas no son iguales.

Comment: Por si las dudas hago notar (solo el op sabrá si es lo que él busca, claro) que tu respuesta solo aplica siempre y cuando los valores a comparar se encuentren en la misma posición, mientras que el código que el mismo proporciona hace la comparación sin importar la posición, es decir, el id del 1er elemento de listaAnterior podría ser igual al id del segundo listaActual y aun así sería válido.

Comment: Interesante observación, si ese fuera el caso pues tendría que hacer un orderby por el campo id, a ambas listas y problema resuelto